# Google Apps - possible to transition only some users?

Tags: google-workspace

Google Apps is now rolling out the use of many more services. One thing [the FAQ](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181867) doesn't explain is whether the choice to allow these services are for the entire domain, or whether I can turn this on for a few test users first and later turn it on for all users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can [select users to transition](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185240).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful link. From there I also found this link which addresses another concern: I can migrate my Reader feeds but existing content (starred items, followers, etc etc) will not be migrated. http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?answer=181118